# Converting an array of 26 integers to char's (alphabet)

Tags: java

I am using the java scanner to input strings of text from the keyboard then having my program create a table that outputs a-z and displaying the number of each letter found within the inputted string. (letter frequencies)

My driver/main class

```
import java.util.*;

public class LetterDriver{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    LetterProfile profile = new LetterProfile();
    String tScan = " ";
    int numReturns = 0;
    while(numReturns < 2){
      tScan = s.nextLine();
      if (tScan.length() == 0){
        numReturns++;
      }
      else{
        profile.countChars(tScan);
        numReturns = 0;
      }
    }
    profile.printResults();

  }

}
```

My Profile class

```
public class LetterProfile {
  int score[] = new int [26];

   public void countChars (String s) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    char a = 'a';
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      int next = (int)s.charAt(i) - (int) a;
      if ( next<=26 && next >= 0)
        score[next]++;


    }
 }

    public int largestLength() { 
      int largest = 0;
      int largestindex = 0;
      for(int a = 0; a<26; a++) {
        if(score[a] > largest) {
        largest = score[a];
        largestindex = a;

      }
      }
      return (char)largestindex;

    }


    public void printResults() {
       largestLength();

      System.out.println(("Most Frequent") + (" :") + largestLength());
    }
}
```

The program compiles, when I run it it allows me to put my input in but the only output it gives me is the most frequently used letter in the form of a number (since my array is 0-25, with 0 = a, 1 = b)

Basically what I'm having trouble trying to do is having my code output a table of a-z while displaying the letter frequencies beside it. Is there a simple way of getting this done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand - of course all it does is print the most frequent letter - that's all that the `printResults` method does.

Simply loop through the `score` array and print each of the scores next to the corresponding letter and you should have the entire frequency table.

Add this to the code already in the `printResults` method. The result is that it will print the most frequent letter first, followed by a list of letter frequencies, starting with the number 1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
    System.out.println( (i+1) + ": " + score[i]);
}
```

For example:

```
Most frequent: e
1: 5
2: 0
3: 2
4: 0
5: 15
...
```

Etc.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out a method of how to go about doing this

Comment: Ah gotcha. Updated with a loop - my bad.

Comment: Wow, finally Somewhat making progress the only problem I have now is displaying the alphabet alongside rather than the number. Thanks so much.

Comment: @smit unfortunately not :(

Comment: @aiuna What is the output you are getting? `System.out.println( (char)(i+65) + ": " + score[i]);` I think this will do the trick.

Comment: Hazzah! It worked, except i switched it to 97 for lowercase. Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<score.length; i++){
System.out.println(score[i]);
}
```

And also, give [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) a read to familiarize yourself with for statements.